# Wifi on Ubuntu 22.04 Macbook pro 2018 Intel chip

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

There is an amazing thread on this here - [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Which sadly does not mention the 4464 adaptors. My machine (a 2018 Macbook Pro with an intel chip has the following)

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:07bf]
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
    Region 0: Memory at 81400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at 81000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

The adaptor is not listed in the various responses, and I have tried all the options to no avail - still no wifi!

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` gives :

```
[    2.306318] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    2.306471] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.416065] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    2.417728] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,kauai-HRPN-u-7.5-X0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418243] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,kauai-HRPN-u-7.5.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418276] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,kauai-HRPN-u.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418307] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,kauai-HRPN.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418337] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,kauai-X0.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418367] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.apple,kauai.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418398] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie.bin failed with error -2
[    2.418401] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: brcmf_pcie_setup: Dongle setup failed
[    2.418418] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_fw_crashed: Firmware has halted or crashed
[    3.070049] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work with the 14e4:4464 version?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I suspect that you need but are missing the required firmware. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep brcm` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 - I wanted to add this to the original thread, but wasn't sure it was the right spot. I added the brcm part for more info, thank you so much already for looking at this!

Comment: I have Googled extensively to try to find brcm/brcmfmac4364b2-pcie and found a few questions but no answers; more specifically, anywhere to download the .bin file. If you still have MAC OS available, here is a site that seems to illustrate how to extract the files from MAC.https://gist.github.com/sebnyberg/ccf6b6c37df99a125bc2346977284622?permalink_comment_id=4271341  You might try a USB wireless until the file becomes available to download. I'm sorry that I have no better suggestion to offer.

Comment: You are sorry to not have better suggestions? This is super helpfull! I'll try this later today or tomorrow, and will let you know the result. Extrating the file(s) from the original OS seems the way to go for now. Thank you so much for the responses!!